# How to split a FlexTable across more than 1 page? PDF output, RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdf-generation, flextable, pdfdocument

How to fix Float too large for page by 281.56999pt on input line 453?

Here's an example rmarkdown file:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(flextable)
data <- mtcars[1:50,1:8]
ft <- flextable(data)
autofit(ft)
````

```
>LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 281.56999pt on input line 453.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I haven't fully explained what I mean. The end part of the table generated by `flextable::flextable()` is not shown on the next page in the pdf file.  Here is another example of the tables generated with `KableExtra::kable()` and `FlexTable::flextable()`.

````
---

output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(iris[1:80,])
flextable::flextable(iris[1:80,])
````

Comment: don't add `results='asis'`

Comment: I have tried, but it still doesn't work((

Comment: So there were 2 issues, first was to get rid of `>LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 281.56999pt on input line 453`. Solved by `set_table_properties(ft, layout = "autofit")`. The second, "multi page" is probably a bug in flextable (introduced with 0.6.1)

Comment: Regarding the second problem, I think you are right. I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem but I can't fix it. I hope it will be fixed in near future. Thanks!

Comment: It is, I will try to push the fix this evening, just want to check it does not break anything (I am newbie in latex and I made a stupid mistake :/)

Comment: you can get the github version, it contains the fix for multipage tables

Comment: Great, now it is ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `set_table_properties(ft, layout = "autofit")` will let latex do the column sizing:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(flextable)
data <- mtcars[1:50,1:8]
ft <- flextable(data)
set_table_properties(ft, layout = "autofit")
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that I did not explain my problem correctly, so I have tried to explain it once more. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65253824/14807779